# Reverse array with custom keys, keep keys intact?

Tags: php, key, reverse

First post here, and a new PHP developer. :x I'm looking for a way to iterate through the LAST four elements of an array, then break. The array keys are custom IDs for the products sold on a website, so I can have the flexibility of adding additional items and have it show the four newest items dynamically on the main page. I almost had it using *array_reverse*, until I realized that it cleared the custom keys.

Is there an easier way that I could be doing this?

```
    <?php
        $products_reverse = array_reverse($products);
        $count = 0;

            while ($count < 4) {
                foreach ($products_reverse as $product) {
                    $shirt_id = key($product);
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo '<a href="' . 'shirt.php?id=' . $shirt_id . '">';
                    echo '<img src="img/shirts/shirt-' . $shirt_id . '.jpg"> </a>';
                    echo '<p>View Details</p>';
                    echo '</li>';
                    $count++;
                }
           }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks - while digging through PHP forums and SO, I found a few problems with my code. _array_slice_ should fix my issue with retaining keys, and my iterations were also broken. It looks like this should work once I get my arguments set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$latest_arr = array_slice($products, 3);
```

Edit : 
To preserve keys by the way, set the fourth argument to true

Comment: Are you sure it's not `-3` though?

Comment: @Hassan im not solving the problem, let her, dont spoon feed

Comment: Well, I think that should have been stated then. +1 regardless.

Comment: Ok, I now have a nice, neat block that returns the last four products of the array! There doesn't appear to be an argument to pass to reverse them in order, however, and reversing the array slice would bring me back to my initial problem.

Comment: just use both functions

Comment: I somehow didn't catch that both array_reverse AND array_slice accept a boolean argument for preserving keys. -.- Thanks, guys.

Comment: you can mark it as correct one, upvote the biggest arrow in the left :3